# ionic performance issues while opening a dialog

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

i have a page where i am opening a dialog showing a list of countries to pick from. but the whole experience is very laggy and i am unable to understand why.

here is the code that opens the dialog and what the page looks like:

```
 async pickCountry(phoneType:string){
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: CountryPickerComponent,
      componentProps: {
        "selected": this.mobCountryCode
      }
    });

    await modal.present();
```

the dialog page is

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar  color="primary">
    <ion-title>
      Select Country
    </ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-icon  name="close" size="large"  (click)="cancel()"></ion-icon>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content> 
  <ion-searchbar placeholder="search country" (ionChange)="doSearch()" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" enterkeyhint="search"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="selected">
    <ion-item *ngFor="let country of countryList">
      <ion-radio value="{{country.value}}"></ion-radio>
      <ion-label>{{country.label}} ({{country.value}})<p>Dialing Code: +{{country.code}}</p></ion-label> 
    </ion-item>
  </ion-radio-group>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
<ion-footer>
  <ion-row style="padding-top: 20px;">
    <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
      <ion-button  color="secondary"  (click)="select()">Select</ion-button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

Code to fetch country list which is done only once when app load is like below

```
fetchCountries(){
    const doc = ref(this.db, "/config/countries");
    
    return get(doc).then((snapshot) => {
      return snapshot.val();
    })
  }
```

Notice the behavior here where first popup opens slowly and then the keyboard comes up slowly and then closing is also laggy.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/vt34kp9sjj4ulcl/RPReplay_Final1677497957%202.MP4?dl=0

Comment: How do you get the `countryList`, in a modal through some subscription? If so, please paste that code block too, and when you're requesting it.

Comment: updated the code but just for you to know this code is called only once so should not be a performance hit everytime